How to change the order of displayed items in horizontal RecyclerView using GridLayoutManager with constructor?
I want to create a horizontal RecyclerView that displays the items in such form:
Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5  | Item11 Item12 Item13 Item14 Item15
Item6 Item7 Item8 Item9 Item10 | Item16 Item17 ...

As you can see, the items are being populated from left to right, and the default way of populating in GridLayoutManager is top to bottom.
I want to be able to set the layout manager and specify the number of columns and rows in the constructor for it do display in left-to-right manner.
The code that displays the example grid should look like this:
_binding?.horizontalRecyclerView?.layoutManager =
            CustomLayoutManager(requireActivity().applicationContext, rows = 2, columns = 5, isReversed = false)

The RecyclerView should also be scrollable HORIZONTALLY.
For now, I have managed to create this RecyclerView with horizontal scroll and custom number or rows and columns, but the numbers are being populated in the wrong order and I cannot find a way to set the number of columns. Here is my basic code:
internal class CustomLayoutManager(
    context: Context,
    rows: Int,
    private val cols: Int,
    isReversed: Boolean = false
) : GridLayoutManager(context, rows, HORIZONTAL, isReversed) {

    override fun checkLayoutParams(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): Boolean {
        lp.width = width / cols
        return true
    }

    override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean = true

    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean = false
}

Can you help me with this?

You have basically nothing. The issue with this task is grid layout manager is extending linear layout manager and breaking it into spans (so columns in your case), there's no simple way to "change the order" as it would basically mean populating items in previous rows which causes A LOT of problems with how measuring works. So for this case I'm not sure you can even extend grid layout manager and creating a layout manager from scratch is a couple of days of work.

Well, the rows and columns are all good, the only think missing is the population order. I was thinking of maybe utilizing adapter for that? There is a position argument that maybe we could use for calculating where to put the data or sth?

Reordering your data for the adapter is probably the easiest and fastest way to achieve it. Only drawback is your animations will get "messy" if your list is mutable or you're attempting to add drag & drop support.

Yeah, adding animations and drag & drop is a must, I will be adding it. Is there seriously no method that you can override or sth to change the order? It seems crazy that such simple tweak means this much work

My other idea would be to use LinearLayoutManager, but I don't think there is a way of displaying multiple rows there

If you dive into source code of grid and linear layout managers you'd realize how complex of a mess it is, even if you ignore out all the excess methods that handle accessibility or edge cases. The biggest issue is of course how item size measurement works, as those classes are so widely used they have to handle a lot of misuse. It seems easy or basic since you have constrain of "all items being same size" but there's no room to apply it in source implementation.

Yeah, but you can extend from GridLayoutManager and override some methods. I just wonder which method would be responsible for displaying the elements in particular order
